# Xgboost custom eval function using Xvars

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

I want to build a custom evaluation function that xgb could use. It is essentially  weighted average function across multiple groups. AFAIK from xgboost's documentation a sample custom eval call is somewhat like this :

```
def custom_loss(yhat, dtrain):
    y = dtrain.get_label()
    return 'mae', mean_absolute_error(np.exp(y)-shift,
                                  np.exp(yhat)-shift)
```

What I would want to pass with this is my dataframe as well. so the function call could be something like :

```
def custom_loss(yhat, dtrain, X):
    y = dtrain.get_label()
    # Do some groupby with X and so on....
    # Get wrmse here 
    return 'wrmse', wrmse
```

Where X could be my train/eval dataframe. Could someone please let me know if there is a way to achieve this ?

My second point is that even if I am able to pass this "X"(train/eval dataframe) will it be a DMatrix object? If yes is there some way to extract columns from this ?

Comment: I don't think the function cares about its arguments. Just do it and return String, Value. If things go wrong, show the errors and we'll take it from there.

Comment: @EranMoshe  Hmm, so the error is this : TypeError: 'DMatrix' object is not subscriptable. This is because I am trying to access a DMatrix object's column like a pandas dataframe.

Comment: show me the code